# Find name of the city using the GPS on the phone

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps, location

I know how to get the name of the city based on the coordinates using this method:

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.UK);
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(52.95477000, -1.15808600,1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {
                StringBuilder cityName = new StringBuilder();                
                cityName.append(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                txtLat2.setText(cityName.toString());
                //Check if the user is in allowed cities
                if(cityName.toString().contains("Nottingham") )
                {
                 //If correct allow user to continue
                 enableDisableButtons(true);                
                }
                else
                {
                 //If not print a message
                 alert();
                 locationManager.removeUpdates(this);                
                }
            }
```

But I want it to work only for specific cities. However I noticed that city such as Nottingham in UK has many different cities around the world with the same name such as Nottingham in US. My question is is there a way to make sure the user is in allowed cities (in my case Nottingham UK and not Nottingham US)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(52.95477000, -1.15808600,1);

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the country code (ISO 3166-1) from the returned address object, and use the country code/city list as a combined filter. See developer page on all available methods for Address : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.UK);
    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(52.95477000, -1.15808600,1);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    {
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
        String city    = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

        //Check if the user is in allowed cities
        switch ( country )
        {
        case "UK":                if(cityName.contains("Nottingham") )
                    {
                     //If correct allow user to continue
                     enableDisableButtons(true);                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     //If not print a message
                     alert();
                     locationManager.removeUpdates(this);                
                    }

            break;
        }
    }
```